# jackson polymorphic deserialize for non-abstract parent class

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, json-deserialization

I'v been using jackson 2.9.0 with springframework. I want to deserialize some jsons from remote that they have no type information inside. But some properties can help me to detect the true type. I used jackson `@JsonTypeResolver` annotation to customize my type resolving.

```
@JsonTypeResolver(ParvanehTypeResolver.class)
public class Parvaneh{


}

public class ParvanehVared extends Parvaneh{


}
```

But there is a little problem: because my parent class (`Parvaneh`) is not abstract, Jackson doesn't  call my `ParvanehTypeResolver` to detect the true concrete class. It just deserializes all jsons into `Parvaneh` class.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a better to use `@JsonTypeIdResolver` with `@JsonTypeInfo` to implement polymorphic deserialization?..

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "@type"
)
@JsonTypeIdResolver(ParvanehTypeIdResolver.class)
public class Parvaneh {
    //...
}
```

More info: [1](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations#jsontypeidresolver), [2](https://www.thomaskeller.biz/blog/2013/09/10/custom-polymorphic-type-handling-with-jackson/).

Comment: My problem is that the base class ( Parvaneh ) is not abstract. and jackson does not call `ParvanehTypeIdResolver` methods. I don't want to make `Parvaneh` abstract.

Comment: @DariushJafari I took this into account - check my code. Also check the first link I provided...

Comment: I cannot use `TypeIdResolver`. my problem is more complicated. some jsons don't have `varedat` field inside; they are considered as `Parvaneh`. And some others have `varedat` field; they are considered as `ParvanehVared`. So when I use `TypeIdResolver` it throws exception meaning " there is no varedat field."